# How can I send a dice/casino/darts sticker as animated in telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I tried to send game stickers in telethon, but I could only send football and basketball stickers as games. Other stickers was static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not 'sticker' they're emoji. You send them as MediaDice file objects

```
import telethon
await client.send_file(chat, 
telethon.types.InputMediaDice(''))
```